# UIPopoverView arrow iOS7 blur

Tags: ipad, ios7, uipopoverbackgroundview

I'm attempting to implement the blur effect from the toolbars in iOS7 in a popover using a UIPopoverBackgroundView subclass. The actual view basically just has a navigation bar that fills the view and that's working fine, but I haven't found a 
way to use the same effect on the arrow that points to the origin of the popover. See screenshot below.

The arrow is currently just a .png, and the main view is already has the blur effect.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to make a UIView, UINavigationBar, UIToolBar, etc. into a triangle or somehow show only a triangle of the view so that it can be used for the arrow?